# Tag Request : `golf-jelly`

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have a question concerning how one of the operators in [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) works (the `G` monad in particular, but that's irrelevant). I noticed there isn't a tag for it, and that I have much too poor a reputation to add a tag myself. Since there already is a tag for a language of the same name, I'm assuming that `golf-jelly` would be the most sensible name. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: I feel like this tag's description should include an explanation that this is only to be used for questions about or involving the Jelly language, and questions about golfing code should go on the code golf stack exchange if it does get created.

Comment: You can ask in [Jelly chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32533/jelly) or [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) instead. That way you can receive more answers, too.

Comment: Also -- [there is a question on StackOverflow about Hexagony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224096/trying-to-learn-hexagony) that remains unanswered until I post that in TNB. So yes, posting on SO won't give you good answers. (Hexagony doesn't have its own tag too)

Comment: @user202729 thanks so much! I was unaware there was a Jelly chat room, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, golf-jelly seems a little unrefined, for lack of a better word. It isn't exactly the most descriptive and will be hard for other users to locate or recognize.

For those who don't know, Jelly is a python library for golfing code.

In my opinion, based on the fact that it is essentially a library, albeit it is also a language per se, I would suggest naming the tag [jelly.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jelly.py) for legitimate questions about the Jelly library for code golfing.

I am not active in the python tag, or related python technologies, so perhaps you could ask in the python chat if that would be a good idea for a tag, or maybe someone familiar with the tag will weigh in here.

Comment: `jelly.py` does indeed sound like a better name, I'm grateful you suggested it. As for the python chat, a user responded "If it's code golf then it doesn't really concern the people in this chatroom."

Comment: Correction: Jelly is a programming language by itself, only the interpreter is written in Python.